# Relations between "!!" and "‼" in Chrome/Safari

Tags: google-chrome, safari, emoji

[image]

Please see the attached image.

It's a webpage from https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/stringsandcharacters/#UTF-8-Representation

When I open it using Chrome/Safari, and use Ctrl+F / Command+F to open the find textfield , and search "!!" (double '!'). The search results will include all the "‼" emoji (it's NT double '!').

As we can see,
the UTF-8 code for "‼" is "226 128 188" / "0xE2 0x80 0xBC"
and ascII code for "!!" is "33 33" / "0x21 0x21"

How can Chrome/Safari find "0xE2 0x80 0xBC" using "0x21 0x21"?